# Power series for given expression

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I'm trying to find a power series for the following expression: $\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$. I think I could write this as $$1+iz \,\cdot \frac{1}{1-iz}=(1+iz) \sum_{n=0}^\infty (iz)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (iz)^n+(iz)^{n+1}$$

Is this correct though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculations are indeed correct (a couple of parantheses wouldn't hurt in the last expression), but If you want to show it in *power series form* then you should group terms with the same exponent. Do you see why you should get
$$
1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2(iz)^n \text{ ?}
$$

Comment: No, I can't see how you found that expression. Could you explain this?

Comment: I think the series notation is messing with you; notice that $(1+iz)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(iz)^n=(1+iz+(iz)^2+(iz)^3+\cdots)+(iz+(iz)^2+(iz)^3+\cdots)$.

Comment: Oh I see. I agree, I think it was the notation that was causing the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A general method:

$${1+iz\over 1-iz}={1\over 1+z^2}(1-z^2+2iz)$$

Let $\cos\theta ={1-z^2\over 1+z^2}\implies \sin\theta ={2z\over 1+z^2}$
So find out $\theta$

Now $$e^{i\theta }=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{(i\theta)^j\over j!}$$

There you get a power series